# I can't show option for default Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying show a option for default with select option in my html with Angular2, but I can't this.

```
   <select name="selectedyear"  [disabled]="disabledPeriod" [(ngModel)]="selectedyear" (ngModelChange)="onChangeYear()">
          <option  name="selectedyear" selected="true" [ngValue]="null" disabled="true">Seleccione un año...</option>
          <option  name="selectedyear">2018</option>
          <option  name="selectedyear">2017</option>
   </select>
```

component.ts ->

```
  public selectedyear: string;
```

When I start the app my select is in white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `selected="true` form first option and use `ngModel`. It will show a option `(assigned in component)` for default with select option.

```js
var selectedyear = 2018;
```

```html
<select name="selectedyear"  [disabled]="disabledPeriod" [(ngModel)]="selectedyear" (ngModelChange)="onChangeYear()">
          <option  name="selectedyear" [ngValue]="null" disabled="true">Seleccione un año...</option>
          <option  name="selectedyear">2018</option>
          <option  name="selectedyear">2017</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

[ngValue]="" instead of null try to use "" instead of null

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select name="selectedyear"  [disabled]="disabledPeriod" [(ngModel)]="selectedyear" (ngModelChange)="onChangeYear()">
      <option  value="">Seleccione un año...</option>
      <option  value="2017">2017</option>
      <option  value="2018">2018</option>
      <option  value="2017">2017</option>
```

Then in the code

```
selectedyear:string; 
 ngOnInit() {
   this.selectedyear = "";

}
```

Probably not the best but this works

Answer (score 0):

No need of selected="true" and [ngValue]="null"
And simply assign value from you component to selectedyear variable.

selectedyear = "2018"; or   selectedyear = "Seleccione un año...";

whatever default value you want.